# How can I correct my tkinter datatype problems?

Tags: python, tkinter, types

I am programming a timer and I think I am close to finish but theres a problem with my code.
As you can see below, I try to update the textbox "countdown" by decreasing the input variable with a forloop. The problem is the input is given as a string and I cant subtract the duration by 1 if the variable is a string. Now I do not know where and how I have to convert the variable from string to integral. I tried to convert the variable timer from string to int but it did not work.
I would appreciate help with my little problem and a explanation why my solving idea did not work.
Greetings

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import time

window = Tk()
window.title("Timer")
window.geometry("150x100")
window.resizable(height=False, width=False)

def get_input():
    activation = False
    timer = entry.get()

    #for test purpose
    print(timer)

    activation = True

    if activation == True:
        for i in timer:
            i = timer - 1
            print(i + " remaining_time")
            time.sleep(1)
            update = True

        countdown = Label(window, text=i)
        countdown.grid()

        if update == True:
            countdown.update
            update = False


headline = Label(window, text = "choose the duration of the timer")
headline.grid()

entry = Entry(window)
entry.grid()

button = Button(window, text = "commit", command=get_input)
button.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

Here is my attempt and Error:

```
def get_input():
    activation = False
    timer = entry.get()
    timer_int = int(timer)

    print(timer_int)

    activation = True

    if activation == True:
        for i in timer_int:
            i = timer_int - 1
            print(i + " remaining_time")
            time.sleep(1)
            update = True

        countdown = Label(window, text=i)
        countdown.grid()

        if update == True:
            countdown.update
            update = False
```

Error code for my attempt:

```
1
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "e:\Wecker\timer.py", line 22, in get_input
    for i in timer_int:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: How do you want count down hour or  minute or second or both?

Comment: I think seconds